# How do I analyze a string?

Tags: string, eclipse

I am quite new to programming in general and i wished to do a cool small program that requires terminal to calculate the planets' position using date. I want to enter the date using day, month and year in a discursive manner *(i.e.today's date, 19/11/2018 is written using 19 novembre 2018 since I'm Italian, translated to english it becomes 19th november 2018)* I made an input using the Scanner library giving an integer variable to year and day and a string for the month... but I'm not able to differentiate the month between one another to do the calculations. How do i do?
Best regards, Red.

Comment: It is hard to understand where _exactly_ your problem is. What _exactly_ is the user input? What is the input the subsequent algorithm needs? Also, it is not obvious what you mean by "Scanner library" and what it has to do with the problem.

Comment: Eclipse is a development environment, **not** a programming language. Which of the many programming languages supported by Eclipse are you asking about?